# Why does my teacher say I should use ‘which I bought’ instead of ‘that I bought’?

Tags: relative-clauses

> My new computer, that I bought last week, has already broken down.

My teacher told me ‘that’ is wrong; it should be ‘which’ as it is an object.
However, I don't understand why I can't use ‘that I bought’.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I'd say your teacher is being a bit pedantic. Lots of native speakers would treat ***which*** and ***that*** as equivalent / interchangeable in your cited context. Which position isn't necessarily affected by whether ***that / which I bought last week*** is set off by commas or not (those commas are *optional*, and should only be included in the written version *if* they reflect noticeable pauses in speech). We can safely assume the speaker isn't singling out *that* new computer (as opposed to *a different* new computer that he bought *three* weeks ago! :)

Answer (score 2):

It probably should be "which" but not because it's an object.

This is a non-restrictive relative clause.  It describes your computer, it doesn't identify it. I know it is a non-restrictive clause, partly from the meaning  (unless you have two new computers, but only one was bought last week), and partly from the use of a comma.

So your new computer is already fully identified by the phrase "my new computer", and the relative clause describes this computer.

Compare that with

> My shirt that I bought last week....

Here the relative clause *identifies* the particular shirt that I am talking about (not my old shirts, but the one I bought last week).

When a relative clause is used to describe you should use a comma, and use the word "which". **A simple rule for learners is: if you use a comma, use "which", no comma then use "that".**

That is the "rule", but unlike some rules, this one is often broken by native speakers, and there are differences of dialect too.